# Adding a /64 ipv6 block, only the first one works

Tags: networking, ipv6, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Ubuntu 16.04.2 server with a /64 block of IPv6s.

If I add the block, like this:

```
ip addr add 2001:41d0:xxx:yyy::/64 dev eth2
```

only the first one works:

```
$ curl -g http://[2001:41d0:xxx:yyy::]/
<!DOCTYPE html>...
$ curl -g http://[2001:41d0:xxx:yyy::1]/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2001:41d0:xxx:yyy::1 port 80: Connection timed out
```

If I add the others one by one, they work:

```
ip addr add 2001:41d0:xxx:yyy::1/128 dev eth2
```

What I am doing wrong?

---

The block is also in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface eth2 inet6 static
    address 2001:41d0:xxx:yyy::
    netmask 64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interface address is a single address, although you can assign a bunch of IPv6 addresses to an interface, so you are really adding the `2001:41d0:xxx:yyy::` address in the `2001:41d0:xxx:yyy::/64` network to an interface.

IPv6 actually allows you to use every address in a network for a host address, unlike IPv4 where the network address cannot be used as a host address, but [RFC 2373, IP Version 6 Addressing Architecture](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2373.txt) defines the Router-Subnet anycast address as the all-zeroes address for a network.

> 2.6.1 Required Anycast Address
>
> The Subnet-Router anycast address is predefined.  Its format is as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> |                         n bits                 |   128-n bits   |
> +------------------------------------------------+----------------+
> |                   subnet prefix                | 00000000000000 |
> +------------------------------------------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> The "subnet prefix" in an anycast address is the prefix which
>   identifies a specific link.  This anycast address is syntactically the
>   same as a unicast address for an interface on the link with the
>   interface identifier set to zero.
>
> Packets sent to the Subnet-Router anycast address will be delivered to
>   one router on the subnet.  All routers are required to support the
>   Subnet-Router anycast addresses for the subnets which they have
>   interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

@Ron_Maupin gives a correct answer but I felt it would be complimented by a simpler one:

/64 doesn't imply the whole block is assigned to the interface. It assigned one address to the interface and tells it that the LAN has the /64 block. This is *almost always* what you want for an Ethernet interface.

/128 is *almost never* what you want for an Ethernet interface. These addresses will not be reachable from the LAN.